# How to transfer Keycloak Config on different enviroments

Tags: environment-variables, keycloak, redhat

We currently have 3 Enviroments, each with a Keycloak Server set up. One for development, one for testing, and one for production.

Now to my question. How do I export/import Keycloak Realms/Clients considering that each one has different root uri's, valid redirect uri's etc...

Is it possible to parameterize that configuration, so i can simply hit export on one enviroment, and import on another? Root Uris and valid redirect Uris would come from the standalone.xml from each enviroment.

Thanks!

I allready tried looking for the export/import documentation from Keycoak and even from RedHat but i dont find anything helpfull.